# How can I fix Array index out of range Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Array index is out of range in Unity, need some help!

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, headDownAngle);
    if(!isDied) {
        audios[1].Play();
        animator.SetTrigger("dead");
        iTween.ShakePosition(Camera.main.gameObject, new Vector3(0.3f, 0.3f, 0), 0.5f);
    }       
    isDied = true;
    isPlaying = false;
```

Comment: of course it is "void" not "oid" in the beginning:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other arrays being used (Unless one of your other functions use arrays) so it seems this line is causing the  error:

```
 audios[1].Play();
```

Remember Arrays are zero based so the first position in an array is actually 0, so if you are trying to get the first element do:

```
audios[0].Play().
```

If you are trying to get the second element, make sure audios has 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Array index is out of range is an error caused when you try to use a part of an array that doesn't exist
example

```
float numOfTests = 2;
AudioSource[numOfTests] tests;

void Start()
{
    tests[3].play();
}
```

since there are only 2 audio sources in the array we can access a third one because it doesn't exist.

I hope this is helpful. I used to code in unity put I moved over to c++ and writing custom engines so if my answer doesn't help that might because I haven't used unity in a year.

Comment: if you need any more help just let me know and if you need any thing in the future just ask me